# Transfering nextcloud data of docker volume to another server while usergroup does not exists

Tags: server, permissions, docker, nextcloud

I'm currently preparing a migration from my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS 64x
to an x86 based server.
In that process, I want to copy all of my Nextcloud data. While investigating the file hierarchy of my current system, I've noticed that I can't access the files from my Nextcloud Data volume. The _data/ directory has the user and user group permission `232073` which does not exist on my Pi. Here is an example of how it looks.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 232073 232073    50598 Oct  2  2022  Nextcloud.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 232073 232073  3963036 Oct  2  2022 'Nextcloud intro.mp4'
```

I'm using the linuxserver.io Nextcloud image, and I've also set the PGID and PUID to my current user (As an env.).

So my question is: can I just copy it and then set the user group and user to the new user on the new server, or do I have to do something else?